# missing external functions in ZIP Virtual File System

Tags: c, tcl, static-libraries, libraries

I am trying to compile zvfs.c [here](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/artifact/cb3672a8fcf73a30) but it gives me error when linking, that the following functions are unresolved external symbols

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _zp_init_keys
.........................................._zp_update_keys
.........................................._zp_decrypt_byte
.........................................._getPwdKey
.........................................._crc_32_tab
```

I am compiling it in windows Visual Studio. does anyone know please which library contains these functions. I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those symbols are only asked for if `ZIPVFSCRYPT` is defined — it requires manual source changes to make that happen — and that should only be defined if you supply a cryptography module. I believe that's a commercial product only; we don't have the source to that.

Comment: Thank you too much. I was using actually another version of zvfs.c which doesn't have this Macro.. but now when I disabled these weird functions with the same Macro in my zvfs.c file, I can compile successfully.

Comment: @moibrahim - please accept the answer if it solves your problem.